# What should be the correct replacement for Node contains in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom

for there is String.contains replacement for Chrome - it is String.indexOf.
I can use, f.e.

```
fatherNode.innerHTML.indexOf(childNode.outerHTML)
```

for nodes.
Is there a better approach?
Thanks

Comment: string includes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes

Comment: Can you clarify what you're trying to do with this? Node.contains works fine in Chrome determining if a node is a descendent. String methods will only be helpful to compare node contents

Answer (score 1):

[`Node.contains()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/contains) is probably what you're looking for.

Your code could be rewritten to

```
fatherNode.contains(childNode)
```

This is also more reliable since it will ensure `childNode` is an *actual* descendant of `fatherNode` and does not happen to contain just the same markup.